# Unable to communication Socket Python from Local Windows system to WSL Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a simple socket communication program in python:
This program is running from windows so that I can fetch the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = "172.19.112.1"#"127.0.0.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")
    data = s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

This program runs in my WSL-Ubuntu system:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = "0.0.0.0"#"117.248.124.120"#"127.0.0.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

The ubuntu is running on its system but when I tried to communicate and fetch output from the Windows system, I have received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\system\Desktop\materials-python-sockets-tutorial\echo-client.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I have tried to use help from microsoft blog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking and have tried this command in power shell:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=65432 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=65432 connectaddress=UbuntuIP address
```

Now I was able to receive output but it was empty value:

```
Received b''
```

Please let me know how I can resolve this issue because I do not know what went wrong with the code. It works fine on the local system but not with WSL Ubuntu.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this? I will be grateful if my socket communicates with the Ubuntu of WSL. I tried the port forwarding approach but it is not working the way I want. It is able to return the client empty message but there is no activity on the server socket where it should have returned "hello world" to me.